# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in line 14 and 29

Tags: php

**Tengo problemas con el codigo, al ingresar al formulario de login me aparece el error  Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in line 14 and line 29, la conexion es estable pero siempre me aparece ese error*

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$contraseña=$_POST['contraseña'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;


$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","loggin");

$consulta="SELECT*FROM usuarios where usuario='$usuario' and contraseña='$contraseña'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($filas){
 
   header("location:home.php");

}
else{
   ?>
   <?php
   include("index.html");

 ?>
 <h1 class="bad">ERROR DE AUTENTIFICACION</h1>
 <?php
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: ¿Pero que te devuelve la consulta? ¿Te devuelve `true` o `false` o el resultado de tu consulta?

Comment: Tiene un error en su consulta, "SELECT*FROM ... debe ser "SELECT * FROM

Comment: @Duston hice la misma consulta con el "SELECT*FROM" asi tal y como esta, y la consulta se realizo correctamente por lo que esa no creo que sea su falla